# Trix editor not rendering stored content

Tags: vue.js, trix

I am using the Trix editor and trying to render some stored content inside the box, but nothing is showing.
My Trix editor component wrapper:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" :id="id" :name="name" :value="storedContent ? storedContent : 'blank'" />
    <trix-editor :input="id"></trix-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Trix from "trix";

export default {
  props: ["id", "name", "storedContent"]
};
</script>
```

The editor on the page doesn't render anything, regardless if I provide the stored-content prop.
It just shows an empty editor.
However, on inspection the hidden input does show the stored-content (or 'blank') on the page.

```
<input id="job-full-desc" type="hidden" name="full_description" value="blank">
```

The 'blank' value gets overwritten as soon as I write anything in the box.

Any thoughts?

Comment: same issue still loking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following , when the component created I manually add the value to trix innerHTML
hoppefully can assist you thaks

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input :id="id" type="hidden" :name="name" :value="value">

        <trix-editor ref="trix" :input="id" :placeholder="placeholder" style="min-height:300px"></trix-editor>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Trix from 'trix';
    import 'trix/dist/trix.css';
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'value', 'placeholder', 'shouldClear' , 'id'],
        mounted () {
            this.$refs.trix.innerHTML = this.value;
            console.log(this.$refs.trix.innerHTML);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Smart workaround. Does it all work as you'd hope now? I used a different WYSIWYG in the end.